# How to escape one double quote with sed

Tags: regex, shell, replace, sed, escaping

I have a webpage that I am trying to edit with `sed`. 
I need to find all the `href="/foa` links and make them say 
`href="www.url/foa` instead.

I've been having a hard time getting it to work.
For normal syntax, I would use `sed -i 's/string/string2/g' <filename>`.
With the forward slash, I escape those with `\/` which works.
but I can't seem to figure out  how to get the single double quote mark into the search and replace stream.

The reason I need it, is to uniquely identify the parts I am trying to replace. `/foa` exists in numerous sections, the only one I need to change is the `href="/foa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable to use sed for HTML manipulation but you can use;

```
sed -i 's~href="/foa~href="www.url/foa~g' file.html
```

Comment: what would be advisable?

Comment: There are DOM parsers available in many languages like PHP, Python, Java etc.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about doing this in php. But my shell script was so close to completion. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Yes PHP is good but unfortunately there is no such utility available in standard Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, which will be flexible, not fix on `foa` only, any links after `href="` will be added

```
sed -r 's/(href=")([^"]*)/\1www.url\2/' file
```